# EOFException thrown by a Hadoop pipes program

Tags: hadoop, pipe, eofexception

First of all, I am a newbie of Hadoop.

I have a small Hadoop pipes program that throws java.io.EOFException. The program takes 
as input a small text file and uses hadoop.pipes.java.recordreader and hadoop.pipes.java.recordwriter. 
The input is very simple like:

```
1 262144 42.8084 15.9157 4.1324 0.06 0.1
```

However, Hadoop will throw an EOFException, which I can't see the reason. Below is the 
stack trace:

```
10/12/08 23:04:04 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201012081252_0016
10/12/08 23:04:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
10/12/08 23:04:16 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201012081252_0016_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED 
java.io.IOException: pipe child exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application.abort(Application.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.PipesMapRunner.run(PipesMapRunner.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVLong(WritableUtils.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils.readVInt(WritableUtils.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.BinaryProtocol$UplinkReaderThread.run(BinaryProtocol.java:114)
```

BTW, I ran this on a fully-distributed mode (a cluster with 3 work nodes).

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Lessons learned: by all means, try to make sure there is no bug in your own program.

Answer (score 0):

This stacktrace is usually indicative of running out of available file descriptors within your worker machines. This is exceedingly common, documented sparsely, and precisely why I have two [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357034/expected-consumption-of-open-file-descriptors-in-hadoop-0-21-0) [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/208506/management-of-available-file-descriptors-within-a-hadoop-cluster) on the subject.

If you have root access on all of the machines, you should consider raising the file descriptor limit for your Hadoop user by editing `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
(Add) fs.file-max = 4096
```

Or issuing:

```
ulimit -Sn 4096
ulimit -Hn 4096
```

Ad infinitum. General information for raising this limit is [available here.](http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/how-to-increase-total-file-descriptors-count-on-linux/)

However, from the perspective of long-term planning, this strategy is somewhat spurious. If you happen to discover more information on the problem, perhaps you can [help me help you help us all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357034/expected-consumption-of-open-file-descriptors-in-hadoop-0-21-0) [Thank you, GLaDOS. -Ed]

(Edit: See commentary that follows.)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, raising the limit didn't work for me. Any more ideas? Meanwhile, I think I will try to post this question on the hadoop mailing list

Comment: I'd be interested in the response. Part of the reason this strategy is spurious is the Hadoop framework doesn't call out its assumptions WRT usage of file descriptors. Specifying an arbitrarily high number obviously won't work in cases where the system oversteps the limit. You might also consider checking the soft file descriptor limit on your system, as Hadoop appears to respect.

Comment: The problem was resolved. It was totally my bad. There was a segmentation fault in my pipes program, which triggered the Exception. However, I do think the Exception looks mysterious to newbies like me. Maybe the Hadoop folks can polish the error reporting a bit?

Comment: I agree. Failures within a mapper or reducer will commonly propagate the error to the top level. General `EOFExceptions` aren't handled quite as gracefully, and as a result are much more difficult to debug in a distributed environment.